# ASP.Net MVC 4. Routing a controller in a separate assembly returns error 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to perform what looks like a straightforward task - calling a controller from a separate assembly in my project.

However, when I requesting information from that controller I'm getting error 404. I have been fighting with it for last 5-6 hours and I suspect that I may be missing something small and obvious, that is why I hope for an advise.

I found on stakoverflow similar question about routing and error 404, but as I implemented another prototype project where I didn't get such error and use a similar code structure, I believe that the problem they describe is different from mine.

For a general picture - the overall goal of what I want to achieve is implementing an area inside an independent project like it is described [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cokobware/archive/2013/01/15/asp.net-mvc-4-pluggable-application-modules.aspx).
I did everything like it is explained in the link for a small prototype (and it works perfectly) and now trying to apply for the real project.

This is how I include an assembly and manage routes:

1. There is a main project with one of the Areas representing a hidden child project "CommunicationBus"
2. "CommunicationBus" project contains a class "CommunicationBusAreaRegistration". Registering a route works correctly, I can get here with debugger and also I can see this route when I use routedebugger (see screenshot below). I also played with namespace for this class, tried to add `.Areas.CommunicationBus` in the end, but it didn't make any difference I could notice.

   ```
   namespace MBVD.MainProject.UI
   {
       public class CommunicationBusAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
       {
           public override string AreaName
           {
               get
               {
                   return "CommunicationBus";
               }
           }

           public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
           {
               context.MapRoute(
                   "CommunicationBus_default",
                   "CommunicationBus/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                   new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                   new string[] { "CommunicationBus.Controllers" }
               );
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. In the Global.asax of the main project I register routes the following way:

   ```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
   {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

       routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new[] { "MBVD.MainProject.UI.Controllers" } 
       );
   }
   ```

   If I reference here "CommunicationBus.Controllers", I can no longer open pages of the main application. However, I believe I need to register here only path to the controllers of the main application
4. Output path for CommunicationBus project is set to bin folder of the main project. Every time I build CommunicationBus I get a fresh .dll in the main project.
5. I added a simple controllers to the CommunicationBus project:

   ```
   namespace CommunicationBus.Controllers
   {
       public class TestController : Controller
       {
           [HttpGet]
           public string Index()
           {
               return "It works!";
           }
       }
   }
   ```
6. I added a link to the main project

   ```
    @Html.ActionLink("test","Index","Test", new {Area="CommunicationBus"}, null)
   ```

   which is:

   localhost:63254/CommunicationBus/Test
7. I use routedebugger and it doesn't show anything suspicious:

[image: routedebugger]

I use ASP.NET MVC 4 for both projects.

I would appreciate any ideas on what I can do to figure out why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are getting this error because of your routing order. Since `/CommunicationBus/Test` matches both `/{controller}/{action}/{id}` and `/CommunicationBus/{controller}/{action}/{id}` the first registered route (`/{controller}/{action}/{id}`) is taking precedence over the desired route, and MVC can't find a controller in the default namespace (`MBVD.MainProject.UI.Controllers`) called `CommunicationBus`.

Try registering your Area routes before your default route. Or, you can just skip that business all together and use Attribute Routing (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx). If you go with Attribute Routing, you will need to ensure you are loading controllers from all namespaces before calling `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` (if you are just including as a reference, this is no problem, it only becomes an issue if you are dynamically loading the reference).